# Function used for calculating not functioning, and a snake that can't be longer than 2?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a snake clone, and I've got the head to the second segment working. The rest of the body checks should run through automatically, but it cuts off the body at the second segment without going through the rest of the segments, despite the fact that it should. My code is as follows:

```
var pixels = document.getElementsByClassName('pixel'); // 0 to 95
var dir = 'right';
var foodEat = true;
var dead = true;
var snakeLong = 1;
var headPos;
var foodPix;
var foodMake = function(){ // Create Food pixel (Not On Snake)
    var tempnum = Math.ceil(Math.random() * (95 - 5) + 5);
    var pixstate = window.getComputedStyle(pixels[tempnum]).getPropertyValue('--state');
    if (pixstate == 'snake' || pixstate == 'snakeHead' || pixstate == 'snakeEnd'){
        console.log('Repeating');
        foodMake();
    } else {
        console.log('Food Made!');
        $(pixels[tempnum]).css('--state','food');
    }
}
var directSend = function(reference,direction){
    if (direction == 'left'){
            reference -=1;
            return reference;
        } else if (direction == 'up'){
            reference -=12;
            return reference;
        } else if (direction == 'right'){
            reference +=1;
            return reference;
        } else if (direction == 'down'){
            reference +=12;
            return reference;
        }
}
var snakeMake = function(refer,tsnakel){ // Continue To Form Snake
    if (tsnakel > 0){
        var tempdir = $(pixels[refer]).css('--goFrom');
        console.log(directSend(refer,tempdir));
        if (tsnakel = 1){
            $(pixels[directSend(refer,tempdir)]).css('--state','empty');
        } else {
            refer = directSend(refer,tempdir);
        }
        tsnakel -= 1;
        snakeMake(refer,tsnakel);
    }
}
var snakeHEF = function(){ // Form First Sections of Snake
    var Pheadpos;
    var tdir;
    if (dir == 'left'){ // Previous Segment Position
        Pheadpos = 1;
        tdir = 'right';
    } else if (dir == 'up'){
        Pheadpos = 12;
        tdir = 'down';
    } else if (dir == 'right'){
        Pheadpos = -1;
        tdir = 'left';
    } else if (dir == 'down'){
        Pheadpos = -12;
        tdir = 'up';
    }
    $(pixels[headPos]).css('--state','snakeHead');
    $(pixels[headPos]).css('--snakePos','1');
    $(pixels[headPos]).css('--goFrom',tdir);
    if (snakeLong == 1){ // No Food Eaten
        $(pixels[headPos+Pheadpos]).css('--state','empty');
    }
    if (snakeLong >= 2){ // One Food Eaten
    var send;
        $(pixels[headPos+Pheadpos]).css('--state','snake');
        $(pixels[headPos+Pheadpos]).css('--snakePos','2');
        var temppos = $(pixels[headPos+Pheadpos]).css('--goFrom');
        if (temppos == 'left'){
            $(pixels[headPos+Pheadpos-1]).css('--state','empty');
            send = headPos+Pheadpos-1;
        } else if (temppos == 'up'){
            $(pixels[headPos+Pheadpos-12]).css('--state','empty');
            send = headPos+Pheadpos-12;
        } else if (temppos == 'right'){
            $(pixels[headPos+Pheadpos+1]).css('--state','empty');
            send = headPos+Pheadpos+1;
        } else if (temppos == 'down'){
            $(pixels[headPos+Pheadpos+12]).css('--state','empty');
            send = headPos+Pheadpos+12;
        }
        if (snakeLong > 2){ // More Than 1 Food Eaten
            snakeMake(send,snakeLong-2);
        }
    }
}
var Game = setInterval(function(){
    $(document).keydown(function(keyPressed){
        if (keyPressed.keyCode == 88){ // Reset Game [x]
            for (s = 0; s < 96; s++){
                var pixstate = $(pixels[s]).css('--state');
                if (pixstate == 'food'){
                    $(pixels[s]).css('--state','empty');
                }
                if (pixstate == 'snake' || pixstate == 'snakeHead' || pixstate == 'snakeEnd'){
                    $(pixels[s]).css('--state','empty');
                    $(pixels[s]).css('--snakePos','not');
                    $(pixels[s]).css('--goFrom','none');
                }
            }
            foodEat = true;
            $(pixels[0]).css('--state','snakeHead');
            $(pixels[0]).css('--snakePos','1');
            $(pixels[0]).css('--goFrom','left');
            dead = false;
            snakeLong = 1;
            headPos = 0;
            dir = 'right';
        } // Movement Set
        if (keyPressed.keyCode == 37 && dir !== 'right'){ // [<-]
            dir = 'left';
        } else if (keyPressed.keyCode == 38 && dir !== 'down'){ // [^^]
            dir = 'up';
        } else if (keyPressed.keyCode == 39 && dir !== 'left'){ // [->]
            dir = 'right';
        } else if (keyPressed.keyCode == 40 && dir !== 'up'){ // [vv]
            dir = 'down';
        }
    });
    if (dead == false){ //Dead Check Then Do Game Calculations
        if (dir == 'left'){ // Move Head
            for (s = 0; s < 8; s++){
                if (headPos == 0+(12*s)){
                    dead = true;
                }
            }
            if (dead == false){
                headPos -= 1;
                if (foodPix == headPos){
                    snakeLong += 1;
                    foodEat = true;
                }
                snakeHEF();
            }
        } else if (dir == 'up'){
            if (headPos < 12){
                dead = true;
            }
            if (dead == false){
                headPos -= 12;
                if (foodPix == headPos){
                    snakeLong += 1;
                    foodEat = true;
                }
                snakeHEF();
            }
        } else if (dir == 'right'){
            for (s = 0; s < 8; s++){
                if (headPos == 11+(12*s)){
                    dead = true;
                }
            }
            if (dead == false){
                headPos += 1;
                if (foodPix == headPos){
                    snakeLong += 1;
                    foodEat = true;
                }
                snakeHEF();
            }
        } else if (dir == 'down'){
            if (headPos > 83){
                dead = true;
            }
            if (dead == false){
                headPos += 12;
                if (foodPix == headPos){
                    snakeLong += 1;
                    foodEat = true;
                }
                snakeHEF();
            }
        }
        if (foodEat == true){ // Food generator
            foodMake();
            foodEat = false;
        }
        for (s = 0; s < 96; s++){
            var tpixstate = $(pixels[s]).css('--state');
            if (tpixstate == 'food'){
                foodPix = s;
            }
        }
    }
    for (s = 0; s < 96; s++){ // Pixel Update
        var pixstate = $(pixels[s]).css('--state');
        if (pixstate == 'snake' || pixstate == 'snakeHead' || pixstate == 'snakeEnd'){
            $(pixels[s]).css('background-color','rgb(0,170,0)');
        } else if (pixstate == 'food'){
            $(pixels[s]).css('background-color','rgb(270,0,0)');
        } else if (pixstate == 'empty'){
            $(pixels[s]).css('background-color','rgb(68,68,68)');
        }
    }
},750);
```

Edit: To reduce confusion, I have now given the entire code.

Comment: `directSend` is the `onclick` for an html button? Where are you calling `snakeHEF`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, I was calling the code to remove the third body segment every time, (lines 76 thru 88) even when the body was supposed to be longer.(I changed it to one '--state' changer, in an if statement checking for a body length of 2) Additionally, an if statement (line 40) was using = instead of ==, causing it to count as true each time, cutting off the fourth body segment.